# Mobile version of careers looks crappy...possible app or?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The careers site on mobile really is awful.  Buttons can be very small or too large.  Drop down lists leap across forms and are not standard across any of the pages.

When you actually get an applicant and you're in the process of clicking "move on to interview phase" or "remove", these buttons are very off in size.  Filters are not abiding by the divs they are wrapped in.

Has there been any consideration to test hiring via the mobile app.  Right now I find myself clicking Switch to Full Site.

What are the upcoming plans?

Comment: Has anyone tested hiring on a boat? If you can remotely [program at sea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19487/295851), you should also be able to hire at sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our mobile version of Careers hadn't kept up with the latest changes to the site, which is why everything was a bit weird and inconsistent.

I've removed this mobile version now, so everything is now the "full site" view. This means that the site is optimized for desktop viewing for now, so you'll have to zoom around a bit, but this seems better than having a broken mobile view.

Longer term, I'm sure we'll have a proper responsive view eventually...

Comment: I'd rather have the normal view and zoom in then have all the buttons and drop downs scattered.  Thanks +1.