# Cannot remove "star" rating on applicant

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Via the mobile and [as hard as it is to navigate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319623/mobile-version-of-careers-looks-crappy-possible-app-or) and use careers I accidentally clicked one of the stars to "rate" an applicant.  You cannot remove this star though, can we have a feature request for "Remove Rating"?

[image]

Right now one of my candidates has a rating he / she does not deserve and I cannot remove it.